# Can I move an element to another element with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Can we swap items from different div using CSS?
I need to move item duaA to satuA and otherwise. Is it possible?

I have something like this:

```
<div id="satu">
    <div class="satuA"></div>
    <div class="satuB"></div>
</div>
<div id="dua">
    <div class="duaA"></div>
    <div class="duaB"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It might not be possible with CSS, but you can use JavaScript.

Comment: CSS? Move? You can position them, you are not physically moving it.

Comment: from a common grid parent and subgrid, it would be possible, but at the moment only FF is able to do it, display:grid/contents could also help. Maybe this should be updated from the server ? at last , javascript on browser side.

Comment: Many things are possible with css - not real-time swap rather order of display while load or content on :hover etc

Comment: could be nice also to clarify if you want only 2 of them or all the four of them to swapped in which position? ...

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
display: flex;
direction: rtl;
align-items: right;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div id="satu">
    <div class="satuA">satuA</div>
    <div class="satuB">satuB</div>
</div>
<div id="dua">
    <div class="duaA">duaA</div>
    <div class="duaB">duaA</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Do you need like that way. I have used Direction css.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use CSS to swap physical content (if you mean that), but it is in JavaScript.

```js
function swap() {
  const satu = document.getElementById("satu").innerHTML
  const dua = document.getElementById("dua").innerHTML

  document.getElementById("satu").innerHTML = dua
  document.getElementById("dua").innerHTML = satu
}

swap()
console.log(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="satu">
    <div class="satuA"></div>
    <div class="satuB"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="dua">
    <div class="duaA"></div>
    <div class="duaB"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following my first comment, Here is a `grid` possibility from a common container for both parents:

---

Follow my second comment : Is it 2 or 4 of them to swap and then, to which position exactly? Is it a simple row, a simple column or a columns and rows layout? , if snippet below do not answer your question.

---

grid demos:

```css
#satudua {
  display: grid;
}

div div {
  margin: 4px;
  border: solid 2px;
}

#satu,
#dua {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr)
}

.satuA {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
  color: green
}

.duaA {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  color: tomato
}

.satuB {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.duaB {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

div div div:first-of-type:before {
  content: ' Swapped ';
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="satudua">
  <div id="satu">
    <div class="satuA">satuA</div>
    <div class="satuB">satuB</div>
  </div>
  <div id="dua">
    <div class="duaA">duaA</div>
    <div class="duaB">duaB</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or was it side by side ?

```css
#satudua {
  display: grid;
}

div div {
  margin: 4px;
  border: solid 2px;
}

#satu,
#dua {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr)
}

#satu>div {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

#dua>div {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

#satu>.satuA {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  color: green
}

#dua>.duaA {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  color: tomato
}

div div div:first-of-type:before {
  content: ' Swapped ';
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="satudua">
  <div id="satu">
    <div class="satuA">satuA</div>
    <div class="satuB">satuB</div>
  </div>
  <div id="dua">
    <div class="duaA">duaA</div>
    <div class="duaB">duaB</div>
  </div>
</div>
```